# Libreoffice Writer - Restart footnote numbering for each page

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice, word-documents

How can I **restart footnote numbering** for **each page** in LibreOffice Writer? *(All footnotes will **start with 1** for each page)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Navigate the Tools > Footnotes/Endnotes menu/submenu entry, then go to the footnotes tab.

The second item down is called "Counting" and you can choose per page/chapter/document.

Comment: thanks a lot @NGRhodes for your quick reply. Worked like a charm!